# PHP error reading remote file

Tags: file

When I try to do a file('http://somewebsite.com') i get an error

"URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration"

I tried using ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On'); but that didn't work.

I'm using shared hosting.  Any suggestions?

All I want to do is read the html source code of a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On php version>4.3.4 and <6, you [can't set `allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in your script. Try using [curl](http://php.net/curl) instead.

Comment: great!  Curl did the job.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting allows and reads custom `.htaccess` files, try putting the following line to a `.htaccess` at the root of your project:

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen on
```

and see if it has an effect...

Comment: I tested out of curiosity, and it gave me an Error 500 - Internal server error.  Maybe my provider just won't allow it.